# Importing miniDV using passthrough on Elura 85 not working

Tags: camcorder, mini-dv

First, I have an old VHS unit that I confirmed working by outputting tape to our current TV.

I then connected the VHS unit to the Canon Elura 85 using the provided cables. I switch it to playback, AV>DV to ON and played the tape.

I see nothing on the viewfinder of the Elura. Well, nothing except some black lines jumping here and there.

I think the Elura isn't sensing full video playback, that it's a blank tape perhaps? Not sure if there's a setting that would tell it to ignore whatever it thinks as blank tape and just play the noise?

**Update #1**

I'm assuming the Elura is thinking that the VHS is spewing ghost signal...
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/24448/Canon-Elura-80.html?page=84

**Update #2**

I also tried other various home video tapes and got the same results.

Comment: What VHS tape are you trying to copy? Is it a commercial video or a home video?

Comment: It's a VHS tape of home videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the cable (STV-250?) linking the VHS to my camera that was the problem. After borrowing one from a friend, it worked and I'm now capturing video.